# How to access Hidden Field of Parent page from child page

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my ASP.NET main page I have one hidden field and and one button. When the user clicks the button I am showing the pop up (child page). I need to access a Hidden field while the pop up is loading. How could I access the Hidden field using c#?

Comment: Please give us the context: Windows Forms, ASP.NET, MVC, WPF, Silverlight?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can pass the value of the hidden field to the query string of the pop up. Something like this:

```
<asp:button id="ButtonInMainPage" runat="server" onclick="Popup();return false;" />
<asp:hidden id="hiddenValue" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Popup()
    {  
       window.open('Child.aspx?hiddenValue='+document.getElementById('<%=hiddenValue.ClientID%>').value);
    }
```

In child page_load:

```
string hiddenValue = Request.QueryString["hiddenValue"];
```

What I show is simple code, you must add necessary check or other according to your project.

Comment: The value i am storing in hidden field its too long.I can't use Query string.

Comment: It might  exits Query string maximum value.so i am going for hidden field.

Comment: Then you can store it in the `Session["hidden"] = XXXX;`

Comment: Then how can i store a value in session using javascript

Comment: I think the question you asked is not the "real one", not the "original one", why not post the first problem?

Comment: No Danny its real one.I am new to ASP.NET Currently i am passing the Hidden field value as Query string.i got my value truncated when its reached the maximum value.So i decided to go for Hidden filed but u suggested me session.

Comment: Where is the value of the hidden field from? I think you give value to it in the code behind like `hiddenField.Text = XXXX;`. Why not use `Session["hidden"] = XXXX;` here?

Comment: I am getting Hidden field value in javascript its collection of IDs the that user selected Rows in Main page.

Answer (score 0):

This is your question:

In main page, there is a gridview, which contains a checkbox column, when a checkbox of a row is selected, add the corresponding ID to a hidden field. When user clicks the popup button, a window will be opened and the selected IDs will be passed to the new window. The question is the IDs are too long to pass in the query string.

My solution:

I think you can remove the hidden field, and remove all client scripts of your popup button.

```
<asp:button id="PopupButton" runat="server" Text="Click to pop up" />
```

Add a server event of the button, like:

```
void PopupButton_Onclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string IDs = CollectTheSelectedIDsInTheGridView();
   Session["IDs"] = IDs;
   string js = @"<script type='text/javascript'>
                    window.open('Child.aspx');
                </script>";
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"showChild",js);
}
```

**EDIT**
Your data list must look like this:

```
<table>
<asp:Repeater ID="myData" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
     <tr>
      <td><asp:CheckBox ID="selectedFlag" runat="server" Checked=<%# Eval("Checked") %> /></td>
      <td><asp:Label ID="dataText" runat="server" Text=<%# Eval("TextData") %>></asp:Label></td>
     </tr>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very Much Danny chen.It helps me lot. :)

Comment: How can i get SelectedRowsID value in serverside.Its Javascript variable.

Comment: Why it's a html control? Since you need to bind data to the checkbox, you need to use a server control. See my edit.